# Convert NULL Text to Null Value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a situation where I may need to pass a variable that could possibly hold a NULL value to a function, but through `sp_executesql`, so I will need to convert it to string value via string concatenation.

#### For Example:

```
declare @var1 varchar(10) = 'value'
declare @var2 varchar(10) = null
declare @sql nvarchar(2000)
.
.
set @sql = '
  select dbo.fn_Scalar(''' + @var1 + ''', ''' + @var2 + ''' )
'
```

#### Function Definition:

```
Create Function [dbo].[fn_fn_Scalar] 
(
    @var1 varchar(10) ,
    @var2 varchar(10) = null
) RETURNS float
AS BEGIN
  Declare @ret float

  Select @ret = sum(value)
  from Table
  where Field1 = @var1
    and Field2 like isnull(@var2, '%')

  return @ret
END
```

What would be the best approach to allow for `fn_Scalar` to be called via Dynamic and Static SQL statements and still allow for the second parameter to either be set to a value, `NULL`, or `default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to `sp_executesql` function like so:

```
declare @var1 varchar(10) = 'value'
declare @var2 varchar(10) = null
Set @ParamDefinition = '@var1 varchar(10), @var2 varchar(10)'

Execute sp_Executesql 'select dbo.fn_Scalar(@var1,@var2)', @ParamDefinition, @var1, @var2
```

Comment: Good, forgot about running a parameterized query like that.  Off-topic Side note:  Will executing this style of SQL help mitigate Injections?

Comment: It helps prevent SQL Injections, [as long as it's used properly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx).

Comment: as with most tools, misuse is very dangerous.